# Why does GetAsync method throw a 'System.Collection.KeyNotFoundException' ? (v4)

Tags: c#, botframework

I keep getting this exception throughout my dialog:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in System.Collections.Concurrent.dll

I have found out this is caused by the `GetAsync` method, but I don't know why. I would appreciate it if someone could give me an explanation to why this exception is thrown, and a possible way of avoiding it.

My code:

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(
    ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // ...

    var uAccessor = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
    var userProfile = await uAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => 
        new UserProfile(), cancellationToken); //throws an exception

    userProfile.UserInputs.Add(turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim());
    await uAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, userProfile, cancellationToken);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The limited code you have posted looks ok. The exception is thrown because the underlaying implementation of uAccessor is a dictionary with keys and values, the exception is saying that it cannot find an item with "UserProfile" (what nameof(UserProfile) returns) in that dictionary. Double check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and maybe take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management) too.

Comment: Thanks. A side note: This exception is not thrown when I run my code with "enable just my code" in debug options (VS2019). So if the key is not found, does that mean that the userProfile.UserInputs is not set either?

Comment: @Lanna, this is by design which makes use of exceptions for control flow and a  default value is created when KeyNotFoundException occurs.